# Centering second title with images and lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

the issue I am having is that I want the "See More" link to be centered directly under each title link. Right now it is just pushed to the right and I cannot figure out how to fix this. If anyone knows how to help me with this issue that would be super helpful. I tried display: block on the "See More" link but nothing happened so I could use some advice. I'm adding a codepen in here instead of a snippet because the lightbox Js is super long. Sorry for any inconveniences. Thank you!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggNmYo

```
<div id="recentwork">
<h2 id="recent"> Most Recent Work</h2>


<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
<h3> Title</h3>
</br>
<a href="" class="more"><h3 > See More</h3></a>
</a>


<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
 <h3> Title</h3>
 </br>
  <a href="" class="more"><h3 > See More</h3></a>
 </a>


<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
  <h3> Title</h3>
   </br>
   <a href="" class="more"><h3 > See More</h3></a>
</a>


 <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
  <h3> Title</h3>
  </br>
    <a href="" class="more"><h3 > See More</h3></a>
  </a>



</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using the outer `<a>` tags for styling, yet setting a secondary link within the block itself. You can 'immediately' fix your  display problem by moving the 'See More' `<h3>` to **directly** below the 'Title' `<h3>`, but the links still won't work, as the parent link will override it. You'll need to close the `<a>` tags immediately after the image to fix that, and use a `<div>` container for each work, rather than an `<a>`. Hope that all makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your project elements to this:

```
<div class="parentdiv">
<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
<h3> Title</h3>
</a>
<a href="" class="more"><h3 > See More</h3></a>
</div>
```

Then, move `display: inline-block` in your css from `#recentwork a` to `.parentdiv`.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/NotABlueWhale/pen/mRZWrX

Comment: I totally understand now why it wasn't working thank you for explaining it so well! I'm pretty new to learning the ins and outs of css and html so this it's always super helpful when people are nice about helping and not condescending towards my questions. Thanks again! @NotABlueWhale

Comment: You are very welcome, good luck with designing your website. @Cakers